# How to get software & hardware information from windows (like dxdiag)?

Tags: c#, system-information

I need to get hardware and software information of Windows like the information we got from **dxdiag**

**Computer module**   : TOSHIBA l775

**Processor**         : Intel(R) i5 CPU M480 @2.67Ghz ..

**RAM**               : 4.00 GB

**Graphic Card**      : ATI Mobility Radeion HD 5650  - 2746MB

**Direct Draw**       : Enabled

**DirectX**           : DirectX 11 Enabled

**AGP Texture**       : Enabled

I need this because I'm developing a server-client application so I can get remote PC details.

I've already googled for some of them, but it looks like each one is clearly different from the other one. I'm also not sure if it would work on any computer on Windows.

So is there a way to get this information from any computer that uses Windows?

I'm using [.NET 4.0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you more,I dont want to explain
Try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: i've already checked that great article .. but it's really difficult to use it, i mean how would i know what's the right key for my information! can you help me with that?

Comment: @Mur Haf Soz its right there in the code in a very clear example. All you need 2 do is match what is populating the labels in the application (for the fields you are looking at) with the underlying query. If you run into a SPECIFIC issue doing so I'm sure someone will help you once you've actually tried.

Comment: Mur Haf Soz , What can I do for you ,Please explain

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add a little bit to the answer by las. What you want you use is something called Windows Management Instrumentation. Full details of the implementation is located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Basically WMI is an SQL like query language that allows you to query various aspects of the computers infrastructure. The link provided by las appears to provide a decent example.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719643%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a link to a sample bit of code that allows you to browse through all the schemas provided in WMI.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you can easily get such information from the registry, or using the System.Management library. It depends greatly on what information you are willing to get.
I made a detailed post which explains how you can accomplish this [Here it is](https://doumer.me/access-a-pcs-hardware-and-serial-ports-with-c-sharp-management-object-searcher/)